# Why isn't Gwibber working?

Tags: gwibber

(I thought I posted this earlier, but it's not here, so I guess I didn't.)

So, Gwibber isn't working. It as kind of almost working when I installed Ubuntu (10.4, 64-bit)--the "broadcast accounts" option under my name was doing what it does, but I still haven't seen the program actually function--and now, it's not opening, and "broadcast accounts" is not opening, but system->prefrences->broadcast preferences is opening.

I had a problem at the beginning where my facebook account wouldn't register properly in "broadcast accounts". Then, I installed some basic update to gwibber, and then that worked fine. But just a little while later, nothing was working at all.

In case this is a clue: the top-right notification boxes seem to show up a whole box-area lower than they should. This is another annoyance, but I feel like it might possibly be solved if I get gwibber working.

Comment: This may not be the best place to post about this.
Instead, please report the bug to launchpad: <https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+filebug>

Comment: Well, I didn't know if it was a bug, or what. I did know that I was looking for a solution, though, and generally, bug reporting is a pretty slow way to get a problem solved--and being told what you're doing wrong is a pretty fast way. Finally, I assumed that "It doesn't open" is a pretty big bug, and if it really had a bug like that, it probably wouldn't have been included in the operating system. But it was. So, if it really is a bug--if I'm doing everything right, and gwibber is just broken--why is it a part of Ubuntu?

Comment: Every software contains bugs. Gwibber is part of Ubuntu because it works fine for most people-

Comment: I have exactly the same situation. Gwibber not working anymore. 12.04 Beta2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filing a bug is your best bet, this isn't affecting all users.  If the software doesn't work as expected, it is a bug and it should be filed.  I can't speak for everyone, but I truely appreciate bug reports.  They are a vital part of development, we can't fix what we don't know is broken.

Please help make Ubuntu better by filing a bug and including the gwibber log file which can be found in ~/.cache/gwibber/gwibber.log

Comment: They are. I just figure that if a bug is only affecting some people, those people must be doing something different from the people who tested it--which made me feel either that I was doing something wrong, which is why it only affected me, and that it could be solved by doing something not wrong, which is what I thought I was learning around here.

I submitted it. It's a known bug. They had an interim solution--which is what I was looking for, and hoped to find here.

Comment: It's probably due to using Facebook - I find that Facebook functionality is very intermittent with Gwibber.

Comment: Daniel, what solution do you have? Please post it in answer.